# Is there a way to run a DI scoped service on a timer with .net core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am writing a .net core web-api backend and want to run a code that collects and writes statistics to my database every 4 hours.

In order to do that I need to inject my DB context into some method and run it every 4 hours with a timer, Problem is i can not inject the DB to this static method.

I have tried using ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance but again i can not get IServiceProvider since i also need to inject it.

This is roughly what im trying to get running periodically

```cs
    public class StatisticsProvider : IStatisticsProvider
    {
        private readonly AppCtx _appCtx;

        public StatisticsProvider(AppCtx appCtx)
        {
            _appCtx = appCtx;
        }

        public void LogStatistics()
        {
            //get data from database and generate statistics 
            //Write statistics to DB
        }
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a good idea overall. You should use something like HangFire for this.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, this can be achieve using hosted services. For more information, see [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task).

Comment: @Nkosi Some static method with a timer that will run this service every hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [Where am I supposed to start persistent background tasks in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178792/where-am-i-supposed-to-start-persistent-background-tasks-in-asp-net-core/49193938#49193938), you can leverage HostedServices to periodically perform a routine operation on your .NET Core Application.

One thing to take note: Apart from the code detailed in that SO answer, For .NET Core 2 and above you should utilise this for DI instead

```
services.AddHostedService<YourHostedService>();
```